# HTML5 form validation in a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, bootstrap-modal

I'm relatively new to jquery and javascript. 
The form opens up on clicking the button "Open Modal" in the modal.
Next, when I click on 'Save' in the modal, it should validate the HTML5 form and on successful validation should call another function "addDetails()".

How do I achieve this using existing jquery form validation plugin or any other method? What CDNs I need to refer to while using?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myFormModal">Add Details</button>

        <div id="myFormModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">


            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add details</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="myForm" name="contact" action="#">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="dor">Date of Registeration:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dor" name="dor" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="weburl">Website:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="url" class="form-control" id="weburl" name="weburl" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="myphoto">Image:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myphoto" name="myphoto" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                  <div class="form-group">        
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="addDetails()">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-external-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a Sample Form:

```
<form>
<textarea required></textarea>
<input type="submit" style="display:none;"/>
</form>

<a>Some other button to trigger event</a>
```

Now we have to check if the form is filled correctly:

```
//this is <a> click event:
if (!$('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
$('form').find('input[type="submit"]').click();
return false;
}
```

This will trigger form sending but won't send because there are errors ;)

It appears that html5 validation errors are displayed on input[type="submit"] click :)

Hope will work for You too! :)

Comment: Thanks..but how do I call another function on succesful validation? Should the button type be still 'submit' in that case?

Comment: On Submit call the method you want but inside that method first check the above condition....if result is false terminate or show popup that validation failed..